# Append two string in Jolt based on condition

Tags: json, transform, jolt

Input json:

```json
{
  "accountType": "Admin",
  "id": "aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA",
  "relationship": "DIRECT",
  "accountInfo": {
    "partyTypeCode": "PARTNER",
    "source": "Facebbok",
    "internalAccount": true,
    "category": "Father"
  }
}
```

output:

```json
{
  "key":"aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA~Admin",
  "relationship":"aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA~Admin~0001"
}
```

here **`0001`** is the respective code for **`Father`**

2nd scenarios,
Input JSON:

```json
{
  "accountType": "User",
  "id": "aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA",
  "relationship": "DIRECT",
  "accountInfo": {
    "partyTypeCode": "PARTNER",
    "source": "Facebbok",
    "internalAccount": true,
    "category": "Father"
  }
}
```

output:

```json
{
  "key":"aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA",
  "relationship":"aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA~0001"
}
```

key should't contain append only when is admin should append. but 0001 should append to relationship

output1:

```json
{
  "key":"aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA~Admin",
  "relationship":"aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA~Admin~0001"
}
```

output2:

```json
{
  "key":"aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA",
  "relationship":"aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA~0001"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following transformation

```json
[
  { // conditional for the cases of "accountType" values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "accountType": {
        "Admin": {
          "@2,id|$": "key"
        },
        "*": {
          "@2,id": "key[]"
        }
      },
      "@accountInfo.category": "rel" // assign a new attribute for this value
    }
  },
  { // conditional for the cases of "accountInfo.category" values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "rel": {
        "Father": {
          "#~0001": "&2"
        },
        "*": {
          "# ": "&2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // generate "relationship" attribute
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "key": "=join(~,@(1,&))",
      "rel": "=concat(@(1,key),@(1,rel))",
      "relationship": "=trim(@(1,rel))" // remove trailing whitespace if exists
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the auxiliary attribute "rel"
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "rel": ""
    }
  }
]
```